# DISTINCT Still gives me dups records in results

Tags: t-sql

I am getting double results for every part...so I'm obviously not using Distinct right here or need to use grouping?

example:

```
select DISTINCT p.PartNum,
                p.PartID,
                pn.Name,
                d.[Description],
                n.Note as PartNote
from Part p
            join PartName pn on pn.PartNameID = p.PartNameID
            join ApplicationPaint ap on ap.partID = p.PartID
            join [Application] a on a.ApplicationID = ap.ApplicationID
            join [Description] d on d.DescriptionID = ap.DescriptionID
            join Note n on n.NoteID = a.NoteID
            join MYConfig mmy on mmy.MMYConfigID = a.MYConfigID
            join Model mo on mo.ModelID = mmy.ModelID
where mmy.ModelId = 2673
and substring(n.Note, CHARINDEX(']', n.Note) + 2, LEN(n.Note))= 'Johnson'
```

results:

```
T50015  765963  Some Part Name  SomeNoteA   [342] Johnson
T50015  765963  Some Part Name  SomeNoteA   [343] Johnson
T60024  766068  Some Part Name  SomeNoteB   [342] Johnson
T60024  766068  Some Part Name  SomeNoteB   [343] Johnson
T60231  766093  Some Part Name  SomeNoteA   [342] Johnson
T60231  766093  Some Part Name  SomeNoteA   [343] Johnson
T60232  766094  Some Part Name  SomeNoteA   [342] Johnson
T60232  766094  Some Part Name  SomeNoteA   [343] Johnson
T70134  766150  Some Part Name  SomeNoteA   [342] Johnson
T70134  766150  Some Part Name  SomeNoteA   [343] Johnson
T70230  766153  Some Part Name  SomeNoteC   [342] Johnson
T70230  766153  Some Part Name  SomeNoteC   [342] Johnson
T70230  766153  Some Part Name  SomeNoteC   [343] Johnson
Y50078  766253  Some Part Name  SomeNoteH   [342] Johnson
N30026  766352  Some Part Name  SomeNoteT   [342] Johnson
N30026  766352  Some Part Name  SomeNoteT   [343] Johnson
N50041  766465  Some Part Name  SomeNoteK   [342] Johnson
N50041  766465  Some Part Name  SomeNoteK   [343] Johnson
N60176  766499  Some Part Name  SomeNoteX   [342] Johnson
N60176  766499  Some Part Name  SomeNoteX   [343] Johnson
N60750  766503  Some Part Name  SomeNoteU   [342] Johnson
N60750  766503  Some Part Name  SomeNoteU   [343] Johnson
```

so I'm getting dups even triples on every PartNumber

```
T70230  766153  Some Part Name  SomeNoteC   [342] Johnson
T70230  766153  Some Part Name  SomeNoteC   [342] Johnson
T70230  766153  Some Part Name  SomeNoteC   [343] Johnson

T50015  765963  Some Part Name  SomeNoteA   [342] Johnson
T50015  765963  Some Part Name  SomeNoteA   [343] Johnson
```

so what I want to see is this:

```
T50015  765963  Some Part Name  SomeNoteA   [342] Johnson
T60024  766068  Some Part Name  SomeNoteB   [342] Johnson
T60231  766093  Some Part Name  SomeNoteA   [342] Johnson
T60232  766094  Some Part Name  SomeNoteA   [342] Johnson
T70134  766150  Some Part Name  SomeNoteA   [342] Johnson
T70230  766153  Some Part Name  SomeNoteC   [342] Johnson
Y50078  766253  Some Part Name  SomeNoteH   [342] Johnson
N30026  766352  Some Part Name  SomeNoteT   [342] Johnson
N50041  766465  Some Part Name  SomeNoteK   [342] Johnson
N60176  766499  Some Part Name  SomeNoteX   [342] Johnson
N60750  766503  Some Part Name  SomeNoteU   [342] Johnson
```

So I want only one unique row for each Unique part number, not dup part number rows showing here.

So to put it in other words for example I want this (one row only for a partID):

```
T70230  766153  Some Part Name  SomeNoteC   [342] Johnson
```

vs. dups:

```
T70230  766153  Some Part Name  SomeNoteC   [342] Johnson
T70230  766153  Some Part Name  SomeNoteC   [342] Johnson
T70230  766153  Some Part Name  SomeNoteC   [343] Johnson
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've omitted part names and notes from your example, but I believe `DISTINCT` means that it should omit rows from the results where *all* of the columns you've specified are duplicated, not *any*.

So since you've specified `p.PartNum`, `p.PartID`, `pn.Name`, `d.[Description]`, and `n.Note`, only rows where *all* of those values are duplicated will be removed.

For example, you've said your results included:

```
T70230  766153  Some Part Name  SomeNoteC   [342] Johnson
T70230  766153  Some Part Name  SomeNoteC   [342] Johnson
T70230  766153  Some Part Name  SomeNoteC   [343] Johnson
```

If those rows were really:

```
T70230  766153  CoolWidget1  "So much fun!"     [342] Johnson
T70230  766153  CoolWidget1  "Buy one today!"   [342] Johnson
T70230  766153  CoolWidget2  "Buy one today!"   [343] Johnson
```

Then all three rows will remain, as none have the *exact* same values for all five of the column names you've listed for the `DISTINCT` operator.

Comment: gotcha...yea there is a difference in the [] numbers sometimes

Comment: that was it.  So since I do not need the [] numbers, I trimmed that out of the last column so that they all say Johnson...and then the distinct worked fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you have duplicated rows in your join.  Remember, the Distinct doesn't necessarily filter on the columns in the select list (read up on this here: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/12/13/select-distinct-order-by-error.aspx).

There's a number of solutions, fort this from:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
select          p.PartNum,
                p.PartID,
                pn.Name,
                d.[Description],
                n.Note as PartNote
from Part p
            join PartName pn on pn.PartNameID = p.PartNameID
            join ApplicationPaint ap on ap.partID = p.PartID
            join [Application] a on a.ApplicationID = ap.ApplicationID
            join [Description] d on d.DescriptionID = ap.DescriptionID
            join Note n on n.NoteID = a.NoteID
            join MYConfig mmy on mmy.MMYConfigID = a.MYConfigID
            join Model mo on mo.ModelID = mmy.ModelID
where mmy.ModelId = 2673
and substring(n.Note, CHARINDEX(']', n.Note) + 2, LEN(n.Note))= 'Johnson'
)
```

To using GROUP BY instead of distinct, to modifying the JOIN that is creating the duplicated rows. Something like:

```
select DISTINCT p.PartNum,
                p.PartID,
                pn.Name,
                d.[Description],
                n.Note as PartNote
from Part p
            join (SELECT Distinct Name, PartNameID 
                  FROM PartName) pn ON pn.PartNameId = p.PartNameID
            join ApplicationPaint ap on ap.partID = p.PartID
            join [Application] a on a.ApplicationID = ap.ApplicationID
            join [Description] d on d.DescriptionID = ap.DescriptionID
            join Note n on n.NoteID = a.NoteID
            join MYConfig mmy on mmy.MMYConfigID = a.MYConfigID
            join Model mo on mo.ModelID = mmy.ModelID
where mmy.ModelId = 2673
and substring(n.Note, CHARINDEX(']', n.Note) + 2, LEN(n.Note))= 'Johnson'
```

Comment: yea definitely don't want to do sub selects...bad.  Let me try the group by

Comment: I don't want any sub selects...performance and just bad practice.  Hmm, there has got to be a way without having to do a sub select.  Again the [343] are not always the same...so as Johnathan stated that's probably why I get dups...

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT will combine rows, but they have to be exactly the same.   Leaving off the PartNote field from your select will give you the unique set.

To get the PartNote as you've shown it in your example, the following should work ...

```
    select DISTINCT p.PartNum,
            p.PartID,
            pn.Name,
            d.[Description],
            min(PartNote)
    ....
    group by p.PartNum, p.PartID, pn.Name, d.[Description]
```